# Remote desktop server as daemon

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, kde, remote-desktop, kubuntu

I'm using KRFB as remote desktop server in my Linux Mint KDE. It works fine as usual remote desktop server but I've to log-in then run it manually (or at start up)

How can I run KRFB of any remoter desktop server runs as daemon without need to log-in at first?

Comment: You can use upstart or sysvinit scripts to do so. I recommend you google `upstart create a service` for more information

Comment: upstart works with CLI applications while KRFB is GUI application!